# Can't ping host from VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a VM hosted on a Windows 10 computer through Hyper-V. I used to use cable connection but I now use Wi-Fi. I created a new switch using the wireless adapter and I am able to ping online websites like Google from the VM and the host. I can also ping the VM from the host, but I am unable to ping the host from the VM.

I don't know what's wrong, and probably something simple. Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

Had to enable an inbound rule in the firewall:

1. Windows + R to open Run window
2. Open "firewall.cpl"
3. Go to advanced settings
4. In the menu on the left click "Inbound rules"
5. Click any item once and start typing "File" and you'll end up at something called "File and Printer sharing..."
6. Find the one that ends with "ICMPv4-In" with the profile "Private"
7. Right click it and click enable rule